# Determination of absorption and scattering coefficients, given only the attenuation length

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, scattering-cross-section, absorption

I'm attempting to write a Monte Carlo solution to the radiative transport equation in a highly anisotropic medium with known attenuation length $\lambda$. Due to limitations in our ability to measure the properties in this medium, this attenuation length contains both scattering and absorption information, and I know nothing about the scattering and absorption coefficients individually, *except* that $\mu_{abs} \ll \mu_{scatt}$. The attenuation length is determined by measuring the intensity of a light beam as a function of distance, and is defined as per convention to be the length for which the intensity of such a beam has dropped by a factor of $1/e$.

In my Monte Carlo simulation, I wish to track the paths of individual photons, and to distinguish between scattering and absorption events. I know that, at each step, I can use the Beer-Lambert law to compute the probability of an interaction (scattering or absorption) occurring:

$$P(x) = e^{-x/\lambda}$$

...where $x$ is the path length traversed since the most recent interaction. So, at each step, I can decide whether an interaction occurs by computing $P(x)$, drawing a uniformly-distributed random number on $[0,1]$, and comparing them. I'm not sure, however, how to decide whether to *scatter* (and re-compute the power/intensity according to the scattering phase function) or to *absorb*. Obviously, if I knew the absorption and scattering coefficients this would be trivial. Instead, however, I know only the attenuation length.

**How can I decide when to absorb/scatter, without knowing more about the properties of the medium? If there is no way, what is the bare minimum I would need to measure and/or compute in order to do so?**

Comment: In this kind of calculation, you have to postulate probabilities for scattering and for absorption. These then determine how often you have to choose absorption and how often scattering in the calculation.